# How to get the latest file in a subdirectories with python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a root directory with 5-6 subdirectories, inside this subdirectories i have 9-10 files, and i want a list with the last file for each subdirectories.

The structure is like that:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLIvw.png)

I want a list like: [File2, File4]

Ill try that:

```
list_files = glob.glob("root/*/*")
print(list_files)
```

And then use max function, but is not worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in a loop

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/**/*.zip', recursive=True)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Quoting the documentation for glob.glob:

> If recursive is true, the pattern ** will match any files and zero or
> more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by an
> os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: I'll try this: for file in list_files: latest_file = max(list_files, key=os.path.getctime), but only get one file instead onefile per subdirectory

Comment: Yeah, thx so much. The problem with this code is only get one file, i need the latest file in each subdirectory